# How to verify path to applet ok? applet ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, tomcat, applet, classnotfoundexception

I have an applet in an HTML page served from a tomcat 6 servlet.  The applet element is as follows:

```
<applet code="com.iteloffice.cuba4remedy.cubaapplet.class" name="cubaapplet"
codebase="http://localhost:8080/cuba4remedy/classes" width="400" height="400" MAYSCRIPT>
<param name="populatefunction" value="populatedropdown">
alt="Your browser understands the &lt;APPLET&gt; tag but isn't running the applet, for some reason."
Your browser is completely ignoring the &lt;APPLET&gt; tag!
</applet>
```

On my development machine, the applet is downloaded fine.  But on a target machine with exact same versions of Java and tomcat I get the applet error as seen below in IE9.

```
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_26
Using JRE version 1.6.0_26-b03 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\Administrator

load: class com.iteloffice.cuba4remedy.cubaapplet.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.iteloffice.cuba4remedy.cubaapplet.class
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.iteloffice.cuba4remedy.cubaapplet.class
```

How can I verify the path to the classpath?

E.G. tomcat is on `http://192.168.0.6:8080`

the `webapps` folder is `cuba4remedy`

Should I be able to enter this path in my web browser?

```
http://192.168.0.6:8080/cubaremedy/com/iteloffice/cuba4remedy/cubaapplet.class
```

package statement in the applet is:

```
package com.iteloffice.cuba4remedy;
```

in tomcat folder structure is like this:

```
tomcat_root/webapps/cuba4remedy
```

inside `cuba4remedy` class files are in:

```
WEB-INF/classes/com/iteloffice/cuba4remedy
```

EDIT:

to fix this I changed applet tag as follows and placed the applet class file in the webapps root folder

```
<applet code="cubaapplet.class" name="cubaapplet"
codebase="/cuba4remedy" width="400" height="400" MAYSCRIPT>
<param name="populatefunction" value="populatedropdown">
alt="Your browser understands the &lt;APPLET&gt; tag but isn't running the applet, for some reason."
Your browser is completely ignoring the &lt;APPLET&gt; tag!
</applet>
```

I saw another post about not having access to the same path that servlets have access so simplified.

Changing codebase to / makes it a lot more flexible.

Comment: I just noticed that `applet` element is entirely invalid.  Use a [Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) to check (& correct) the basics of it.  For simplicity sake, reduce the page to include only the applet.  Why does it declare `MAYSCRIPT`?  What scripting does it do?

Comment: `<html>
<body>
<applet
 name="cubaapplet"
 code="com.iteloffice.cuba4remedy.cubaapplet"
 codebase="http://localhost:8080/cuba4remedy/classes"
 width="400"
 height="400"
 alt="Your browser understands the &lt;APPLET&gt; tag but isn't running the applet, for some reason."
 MAYSCRIPT>
<param name="populatefunction" value="populatedropdown">
Your browser is completely ignoring the &lt;APPLET&gt; tag!
</applet>
</body>
</html>`  Try that exact HTML in the validation service.  As an aside, it seems this deployment uses loose class files.  An applet is much easier to deploy and update, with a Jar.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes the use of a jar file makes sense and I will try that.